# Is there any free or commercal jpeg decode which is really fast

Tags: c++, jpeg, performance, decoder

I am using c++, libjpeg for decoding jpeg file.
I find it is not fast enough, is there any method to make it faster by setting some compile parameter?
or are there any other lib can open jpeg files more faster?

now it takes about 750ms to open a 4368 * 2912 4m jpeg image.
I wish this can be reduced to 150ms.
Many thanks!

Added:
IJL seems faster than libjpeg:)

Comment: There is no compiler parameters that can speed up program 6 times.

Comment: As 4MB / 150 ms = 27 MB/s, pure I/O speed already becomes relevant.

Comment: less than a second for a 12.7 megapixel image really isn't bad...

Answer (score 6):

The fastest way is not to decode it at all. Usually you can use a low-res preview first; that requires only the low frequencies. For a 546 x 289 pixel preview, you in fact only need the (0,0) (DC) component.

Answer (score 3):

There's the [Intel Performance Primitives](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp/) which contains JPEG coding/decoding implementations

Comment: @Shay: ok, but the sxingfeng asked for free or commercial software, so 'it must be free' wasn't a requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Also see http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg-turbo/ for a drop-in replacement of libjpeg that uses SIMD instructions for a significant performance boost.

Answer (score 2):

I use [libjpeg](http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v7.tar.gz) from [ijg](http://www.ijg.org/). It's documented how to modify for your purposes, like coding/decoding in memory.

Comment: many thanks!
I also tried to ijl it takes just 600ms on my AMD computer, maybe faster on intel cpu. I think manybe it is possible to take less then 400ms.

Answer (score 0):

I think DirectX and libSDL can decode jpegs - although libSDL might use libjpeg for decoding.